# MAAS 2.0. Importing custom images does not work?

Tags: maas

How should I import custom images to MAAS 2.0.0~beta2+bzr4920 in Ubuntu 16.04 LTS Beta2?

The command I successfully used in 1.9 is uploading an image without errors:

$ maas local boot-resources create -d name=custom/foo architecture=amd64/generic filetype=tgz content@=/tmp/ubuntu1604-tgz

This image appears in MAAS > Images > Generated Images section, but I can't seem to find a way of deploying this image afterwards as only boot images from official http://images.maas.io/ appears in the OS to deploy drop list.

BTW /tmp/ubuntu1604-tgz is a renamed copy of official Ubuntu 16.04 from /var/lib/maas/boot-resources/cache/, so I believe there shouldn't be any problems with the image itself and I'm just missing something out.

```
$ dpkg -l | grep maas
ii  maas                               2.0.0~beta2+bzr4920-0ubuntu2    all          "Metal as a Service" is a physical cloud and IPAM
ii  maas-cli                           2.0.0~beta2+bzr4920-0ubuntu2    all          MAAS client and command-line interface
ii  maas-common                        2.0.0~beta2+bzr4920-0ubuntu2    all          MAAS server common files
ii  maas-dhcp                          2.0.0~beta2+bzr4920-0ubuntu2    all          MAAS DHCP server
ii  maas-dns                           2.0.0~beta2+bzr4920-0ubuntu2    all          MAAS DNS server
ii  maas-proxy                         2.0.0~beta2+bzr4920-0ubuntu2    all          MAAS Caching Proxy
ii  maas-rack-controller               2.0.0~beta2+bzr4920-0ubuntu2    all          Rack Controller for MAAS
ii  maas-region-api                    2.0.0~beta2+bzr4920-0ubuntu2    all          Region controller API service for MAAS
ii  maas-region-controller             2.0.0~beta2+bzr4920-0ubuntu2    all          Region Controller for MAAS
ii  python3-django-maas                2.0.0~beta2+bzr4920-0ubuntu2    all          MAAS server Django web framework (Python 3)
ii  python3-maas-client                2.0.0~beta2+bzr4920-0ubuntu2    all          MAAS python API client (Python 3)
ii  python3-maas-provisioningserver    2.0.0~beta2+bzr4920-0ubuntu2    all          MAAS server provisioning libraries (Python 3)

$ lsb_release -a
No LSB modules are available.
Distributor ID: Ubuntu
Description:    Ubuntu 16.04 LTS
Release:    16.04
Codename:   xenial
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

OK, shame on me. I have forgot to run

```
maas local boot-resources import
```

after executing

```
maas local boot-resources create -d name=custom/foo architecture=amd64/generic filetype=tgz content@=/tmp/ubuntu1604-tgz
```

Took me a while to figure that out.

Since MAAS documentation is rather poor when it comes to importing custom images, I think I'll write short guidelines how to do it.

First you should know that *naming is important*. So if you want to import custom image, you should give an appropriate *name* parameter:

```
maas local boot-resources create name=custom/foo title="Title is not important" architecture=amd64/generic content@=/path/to/your/image
maas local boot-resources import
```

Take a close look at *name=custom/foo*. MAAS is expecting that custom image name starts with *custom*. There is no difference what you write after the slash, so *name=custom/foo* is as good as *name=custom/bar123*.

If you want to import CentOS image, naming is also important according to *src/provisioningserver/drivers/osystem/centos.py*. To import a custom image for CentOS 7.2, you should execute:

```
maas local boot-resources create -d name=centos/centos72 architecture=amd64/generic content@=/path/to/your/image
maas local boot-resources import
```

Yes, exactly. Name parameter should be *name=centos/centos72* for CentOS 7.2, *name=centos/centos67* for CentOS 6.7 and so on. That's how distro match regexp is implemented.

Haven't tried importing custom SuSE and Windows images, but there should be naming restrictions too. Just take a look to MAAS sources in *src/provisioningserver/drivers/osystem/*.